# 'Unchecked call' on ArrayList

Tags: java, android, unchecked

I don't understand why I'm having this errors and how to solve them, on the following code in mine MainActivity file. I've searched on Google but I can't relate the solutions to mine code. I have also passed -Xlint:unchecked to javac, but can't get any wiser either.

I'm pretty new to Android and Java programming and trying to solve any highlights in mine code.

Thanks in advance.

> Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.ArrayList' to
>   'java.util.ArrayList' less... (Ctrl+F1)  Signals
>   places where an unchecked warning is issued by the compiler, for
>   example:
>
> void f(HashMap map) {
>       map.put("key", "value");   }    Hint: Pass -Xlint:unchecked to javac to get more details.

---

> Unchecked call to 'ArrayList(Collection)' as a member of
>   raw type 'java.util.ArrayList' less... (Ctrl+F1)  Signals places where
>   an unchecked warning is issued by the compiler, for example:
>
> void f(HashMap map) {
>       map.put("key", "value");   }    Hint: Pass -Xlint:unchecked to javac to get more details.

---

```
private void readItems() {
    File filesDir = getFilesDir();
    File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
    try {
        items = new ArrayList<>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `items`?

Comment: If you posted the compiler messages as code, not a quote, the type parameters would show up too (e.g. `java.util.ArrayList<java.util.String>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause:** You are using `ArrayList` as a generics type in Java but do not specific a particular type for it. That why the compiler shows that warning.

So what happen when you do not specific a particular type for generics. Here is a scenario.

```
 // You want this line contains only Integer.
List list = new ArrayList<>();

// 1. Warning when add new item.
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);

// 2. Must cast to Integer when using.
Integer number2 = (Integer) list.get(1);

// 3. Do not prevent developers from adding non-integer type, such as String, double, boolean etc.
list.add("Four");
list.add(true);

// 4. Might throws ClassCastException and make your app crashes.
Integer number = (Integer) list.get(4);
```

**Solution:** Specific or pass a particular type for a generic type inside angle brackets `<>`.

```
 // You want this line contains only Integer.
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

// If you want to declare variable first
List<Integer> items;

// Then initialize
items = new ArrayList<>();

// 1. No warning when add new item.
items.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);

// 2. No need to cast to Integer.
Integer number2 = list.get(1);

// 3. Prevent developers from adding non-integer type, such as String, double, boolean etc.
list.add("Four"); // Error when compile
list.add(true); // Error when compile

// 4. You cannot add non-integer type and no need to cast so ClassCastException never occurs.
Integer number = list.get(2);
```

There are many generics class built-in in Java such as `List`, `ArrayList`, `Map`, `HashMap`, `Set`, `HashSet`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because of incorrectly using **generic**. you should normally use generics together with ArrayList to specify the type of objects you are going to store in your ArrayList.

Like this:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

please check the definition of `items` in your codes.